# Vectorization of matrix constraints using CVXPY

Tags: python, constraints, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming, convex-optimization

These is how I am currently writing my constraints  -

```
x = cp.Variable(shape=(len(dogs), len(fields)), boolean=True)

# Each dog must run in exactly one field
constraints = []
for i in range(len(dogs)):
    constraints.append(cp.sum([x[i][j] for j in range(len(fields))]) == 1)

# Each field must not have more than 10 dogs
for j in range(len(fields)):
    constraints.append(cp.sum([fields[i] * x[i][j] for i in range(len(dogs))]) <= 10)
```

I read the documentation that says that vectorized constraints lead to better performance. I changed my constraints to

```
constraints = [cp.sum(x[:,])==1,cp.sum([dogs@x]) <= 10]
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me vectorize the constraints?

Comment: What kind of performance? This quote is probably about the time needed for canonicalization / transforming the model. I don't expect this to be much relevant in your case as `len(dogs)` and `len(teams` is probably << 1 million. I guess solving-time is dominating model-creation by a huge margin and vectorization won't help. Make sure, you use a good solver. Often the default one picked by cvxpy (depends on install-style) is more targeting toy-problems.

Comment: @sascha Thanks, you are right and compile time is being dominated by solve time. I did try the free solvers and they didn't improve the solve time either unfortunately..

My objective function is to minimize the sum of differences within a list - 


    `cp.Minimize(cp.sum([cp.abs(cp.sum(x[i]) - cp.sum(x[j])) for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(len(x)) if i > j]))`

Makes me think that I need to work on improving/changing the objective function?